# PyGame game crashes at a certain place [Complete]

Tags: python, crash, pygame

I'm pretty much blind when getting crashes like what is the problem? When the program is at the state of rabbits spawning here

```
rabbitCounter += 1
    if rabbitCounter >= NEW_RABBIT:
        rabbitCounter = 0
        rabbits.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
    - RABBIT_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - RABBIT_SIZE),
    RABBIT_SIZE, RABBIT_SIZE))
```

It chrashes when I press the space bar to go to the other loop, level 2. I did this so I 
could test the game fine but it seems not to work. Hopefully the problem gets found. It hangs the window gets greyed and the "Program has crashed dialog" comes up.

Here's all the files and py.files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gqke6hfooz7mbnr/Qm8NMlyNqc

It seems to be these two sections if I take a guess:

```
#Gris spawning
    while pigSpawn == True:
        pigCounter += 1
        if pigCounter >= NEW_PIG:
            pigCounter = 0
            pigs.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
        - PIG_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - PIG_SIZE),
        PIG_SIZE, PIG_SIZE))

#Vildsvin spawning
    while boarSpawn == True:
        boarCounter += 1
        if boarCounter >= NEW_BOAR:
            boarCounter = 0
            boars.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
        - BOAR_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BOAR_SIZE),
        BOAR_SIZE, BOAR_SIZE))
```

Answer (score 0):

In level 1 the programmer created 20 pigs, 20 boars etc.. then setup a while-loop that handled events. In that single loop it handled all events (to move the game). Spawned pigs/boars as needed etc..

The code in level 2 just contains a never ending while loop that add more and more pigs.
Probably until you run out of memory. Basically once you are in the pigSpawn loop you just continue to loop forever adding more and more pigs until the program crashes.

Comment: Can you suggest an improvement or solution then cause I've tried 3 times already without results.

Comment: Basically don't create infinite loops. 

Read the logic of your own code. Once the interpreter enters the loop while pigSpawn == True: 
all it does is  increment pigCounter and adds pigs to the pig list endlessly

Compare it to level 1 to see how it should be done